# Explanation of figure:turbulent magnetic field lines + spatial distribution of out-of-plane electric current density

Tags: electromagnetism, plasma-physics, turbulence, solar-wind

The following graph is supposed to present turbulent magnetic field lines along with the spatial distribution of out-of-plane electric current density.

[image]
However I am not sure I completely understand this.

Do the black line represent the magnetic field lines and the red color the current coming out of the plane?
Could someone please explain? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do the black line represent the magnetic field lines and the red color the current coming out of the plane?

Based upon the geometry, I would say yes and yes.  You can infer as much based upon a handwavy approximation using Ampere's law.  Where you see stronger gradients in the magnetic field with a finite curl, there is red.  I am guessing that the regions without red would either have the opposite signed current density (i.e., into the page) or just weaker and the authors chose a saturate color scale for some reason.

> Could someone please explain?

I could explain much more if there were a citation/reference for context.  Without that or additional information, my above explanation will remain limited.

**Update**

Now that I am aware of the paper from which this subfigure was taken (doi:[10.1007/s11214-017-0435-8](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11214-017-0435-8)), I can explain a little more.

[image: Figure 1 from Greco et al. [2018]]

The color-coding indicates the deviation of the probability distribution function (PDF) of the z-component (out of plane) current density relative to a reference Gaussian (see upper left-hand panel in above figure, which is a snapshot from the paper).  The three different plots are used to illustrate where the deviations occur spatially with respect to what part of the PDF is non-Gaussian.

The lines in each of the two-dimensional simulation plots show magnetic field lines, separating positive and negative vector potential regions by solid and dashed lines, respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much! this is tah paper i am refering to :https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321232716_Partial_Variance_of_Increments_Method_in_Solar_Wind_Observations_and_Plasma_Simulations